# Accessing the outer class when inheriting from it

Tags: kotlin, inner-classes

```
abstract class A {
    abstract inner class B : A() {
        init {
            // How can I access the outer class?
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, `this` refers to the class `B`, `this@A` refers to the parent class. How can I access the outer class?

---

Test case:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract inner class B : A() {
        init {
            println("Should display 'Parent': $this") // replace 'this' by something else?
        }
    }
}

class Parent : A() {
    override fun toString() = "Parent"
    
    inner class Child() : B() {
        override fun toString() = "Child"
    }
}

fun main() {
    Parent().Child()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Accessing the outer class"? What exactly do you want to access? There are only two instances here - a `Parent` and a `Child`. To access the `Parent`, do `this@A`. To access the `Child`, do `this`. Do you have a specific method/property you want to know how to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you created two objects - an instance of `Parent`, and an instance of `Child`.

```
Parent().Child()
   ^       ^
   |       |
   1       2
```

So there is really only two different things that you can access from the `init` block of `B`. You can either access the `Parent` object using `this@A`, which is the object *associated* with the `Child` object, or the `Child` object itself using `this` (or redundantly `this@B`).

"Accessing the outer class", which presumably you mean `A`, is not something you can do, because there is not even such an instance of `A`.

You can however, invoke `A`'s implementations of methods/properties using `super@B.xxx` (note that it is not `super@A`. Read it as "super *of* `B`"). Perhaps this is what you intended on doing in the first place.

For example, changing `A` to the following:

```
abstract class A {

    override fun toString() = "A"

    abstract inner class B : A() {
        init {
            println("Should display 'Parent': ${super@B.toString()}")
        }
    }
}
```

would print "A".

Note that this actually calls `toString` on the `Child` object, not the `Parent` object. You cannot do the same to the `Parent` object, because it is a different object. This `init` is creating the `Child` object, right?

In summary, `this` accesses some object that is in scope. `super` accesses a specific implementation of a method/property *up* the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: What I wanted to do was simply access the `Parent`, but I somehow messed up when I tested `this@A` so I thought it didn't work. Thanks for the very precise answer.